# Refresh error in Job Activity Monitor in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I've been using Job Activity Monitor in SQL Server Management Studio to check history of a job that runs. I encounter problem while refreshing it. When I try to refresh it after some time, a big red cross appears. I need to close the monitor and start again from SQL Server Agent.

[image]

Comment: please post the error

Comment: @TheGameiswar -No error.A big red cross appears ,when i refresh multiple times.

Comment: screenshot would help in this case

Comment: @TheGameiswar -- PFA screenshot for the same.

Comment: try to check eventvwr for any additional logs and paste them in question

Comment: NO Additional logs in eventvwr.

Comment: If this only happens with the one job, then try to delete the job and recreate it. Seems like some system/job settings have been removed/changed in some way that the interface cannot cope with. If it happens with more jobs, try to reinstall the interface entirely.

Comment: @ Allan S. Hansen--There are almost 300-400 jobs running ,which are very critical...So reinstalling is not possible..any other way??